PEP563 'if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:' not working with type hint import
Given the following two files:
foo.py
class Foo:

    pass

main.py
import typing

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from foo import Foo


def main(foo: Foo):
    return foo

PEP 563 says this should work but if I run main.py then I get NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined.
Doing some research all I could find on this was a GitHub issue that suggested disabling Jedi in VS Code.
I'm using VS Code 1.93.1 with Pylance v2024.9.1 enabled.
Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

As stated in the PEP, you need to either add from __future__ import annotations or quote the hints (def main(foo: 'Foo'): ...).
